# How to format date like "July 14, 2014" in javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I'm getting date value from jQuery BeatPicker like "14/07/2014", I need to format this value as "July 14, 2014".

Is there any easy way to achieve this using javascript/jQuery/plugin?

Thanks

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to stick with pure Javascript

```
function formatDate(dateString){
  var monthNames = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
        "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
        "October", "November", "December");

  var dateArray =  dateString.split("/");
  var month = monthNames[dateArray[1]-1];
  var day = dateArray[0];
  var year = dateArray[2];
  return month + " " + day + ", " + year;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "14/07/2014";
var output = text.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d\d\d)/, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    return monthNames[parseInt($2, 10) - 1] + " " + $1 + ", " + $3;
});
```

Totally untested, and yes - the regex is messy (should use curly brackets however this reads more easily), but should work about right...

Comment: `should use curly brackets` - Right, you are.